# Testing papertrail in a model concern using RSpec Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec, paper-trail-gem

I have added an `ActiveSupport::Concern` that declares `has_paper_trail` with some additional options in the class method. This concern is included by the actual model, that can now have versioning enabled on it via papertrail

Now I want to test this concern only using RSpecs on a mock model (that does not currently exist in the database), and make sure that the versions table gets populated correctly.

So I have an RSpec where I am doing this :

```
describe PapertrailConcern do
  before(:all) do
    class PaperTrailModel < ActiveRecord::Base
      include PapertrailConcern

      has_paper_trail
    end
  end

  it 'stores changes to model in paper trail versions' do
    # check if PaperTrailModel attribute changes are tracked in versions
  end
end
```

Since the PaperTrail Model does not exist in the database, I get this error if I do any operations on it:

```
  PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "paper_trail_models" does not exist
       LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"paper_trail_models"'::re...
                                                 ^
```

I also considered using Rspec Mock Model, but I am not sure how to enable papertrail versioning on a mock model. Haven't found anything along those lines online

Has anyone run into this issue or would happen to know how I could declare a test model and test if papertrail versioning works correctly on it?

Comment: I think that all classes which extend `ActiveRecord::Base` must have a table in the database. It feels like you're fighting the framework. Also, you are not testing production code (actual models) so I would question the value of such tests.

Comment: You've probably already seen it, but there's a whole section of the PT docs regarding testing: https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail#7-testing

Comment: yeah have checked that section out. the papertrail functionality is isolated in a separate module, and I want to be able to write tests for that module, agnostic of the actual model it is testing

Comment: re: "I want to .. write tests for [PaperTrail itself] agnostic of the actual model it is testing" You are more than welcome to contribute tests to the PaperTrail codebase at https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail. I will be happy to help with that.

Comment: will do @JaredBeck. I'll work on it and create a PR